# It's possible to fully disable windows logs?

Tags: windows, logging

I've configured auditpol `auditpol /set /category:* /success:disable /failure:disable` - the size of the logs has decreased, but I would like to know if it is possible to make them 0... For all channels: System, Application, etc.

Comment: Please do not forget that vastly more people than fewer say "something happened, where is the log?"   Disabling all logs would fall into the bad practice bucket.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://superuser.com/questions/1516725/how-to-disable-windows-10-system-log