# WERS is disabled, system still displaying error(s)

Tags: windows

I have set windows error reporting service to disabled. still receiving system errors on boot, and application launch.

how to i permanently break windows ability to display error messages?

Newish win10 computer, all other variables irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

WERS is the Windows Error Reporting Service. the only thing it controls is whether error information is periodically sent to Microsoft.

You cannot disable windows internal error collection so errors will continue to appear in your eventlog. you may be able to change some of that behavior. see here for more info: [How to disable Windows 10 system log](https://superuser.com/questions/1516725/how-to-disable-windows-10-system-log) . That said, that only really pertains to the logs, not the display of errors.

When programs display errors, its because they were programmed to do so. you cannot change that without changing the code.

so there may be a little more nuance to this than I'm discussing, but it will be the odd program that has a configuration setting that allows you to suppress errors; definitely not a norm.

Answer (score 0):

> how to I permanently break windows ability to display error messages?

You should fix the errors.  Windows may be reporting important errors.

Update all drivers.

Look in Reliability History for important errors. WERS reports often land here and it is easy to see what is going on.

Look in the Event Viewer for detailed errors.

But do not just ignore errors - they are there to help prevent bigger problems. Also numerous errors in Windows cannot be disabled as they can be serious errors.

Comment: I want the ability to disable errors.  I am also looking into reliability history, and event viewer

Comment: Disabling errors is not a good idea as you may have further issues down the line. Some errors cannot be disabled also.

Comment: I understand that you recommend against this because it is a bad idea, and also bad practice, however I will not rest until I find the answer. "Some errors cannot be disabled also" - the error being displayed started after i installed a new rx6600 graphics card and the error is from amdrssserv.exe.  I also disagree with your statement about it being impossible to disable some errors, i could physically delete the bits on the hard drive that are responsible for the errors, so it is possible, however you are saying it is highly difficult, which i could believe, but dont.