# Disable a "Startup event trace session" when Windows boots

Tags: windows, powershell, logging, performance-monitor

OS: Windows 10 Pro 64bit, 21H2, I'm the Admin on this computer.

Although there's a manual way to do this via

```
Performance Monitor -> Data Collector Sets -> Startup Event Trace Sessions
```

However, I'd like to know how to disable DiagTrack-listener and DefenderApiLogger at boot via registry or Powershell. Googled and I could only find a way to disable "Event Trace Sessions" not "Startup Event Trace Sessions" via a powershell script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Registry keys to disable (not start) DiagTrack-listener and DefenderApiLogger:

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\DiagTrack-Listener" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
reg add "HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\WMI\Autologger\DefenderApiLogger" /v "Start" /t REG_DWORD /d "0" /f
```

(I think you can also do this by just [disabling those logs](https://superuser.com/a/1516732/673426) in event viewer, but I'm not totally sure it's the same thing)